# Modify the value of an object in an array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I got an problem to assign a value to an object inside an array.

Let me explain what I did. The **collection** is a struct:

```
struct Collection {

    var selection : Int = -1  
}
```

The **object** is an object which include an array of **Collection** objects, and it's also a struct:

```
struct Object {

    var collection : [Collection]
```

The value is not assigned if I'm using the following code:

```
fun onSelected(index Int, selectedIndex Int) {
    var collection = self.object.collection[index]
    collection.selection = selectedIndex
}
```

This probably because the array is a value type in Swift. Am I right?

Then I changed my code into:

```
fun onSelected(index Int, selectedIndex Int) {
    self.object.collection[index].selection = selectedIndex
}
```

Then I got a compile error, the error message is:

> /Volumes/Macintosh
>   HD/Users/Public/Projects/Test/Controllers/MyViewController.swift:214:9:
>   '@lvalue $T8' is not identical to 'Int'

What happened? What should I do to assign the value to an object inside my array? Thanks

### Edit

I added my [source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/479361/ArrayMemberTest.zip) into dropbox. It includes two methods I used. Please have a try if you're interested. Thanks!

Comment: Can anybody explain. What does the error message mean? Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is somehow related to mutating issue. I define my **object** something like var obj : Object, but it's still immutable. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it will solve the problem if I declare my object like this:

```
var object : Object = Object()
```

Previously I declare it as:

```
var object : Object!
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me:

```
struct Collection {
    var selection : Int = -1
}
struct Object {
    var collection : [Collection]
}

var object = Object(collection: [Collection(selection: 0)])

var collection = object.collection[0]

collection.selection = 1
object.collection[0].selection //0

object.collection[0].selection = 2
object.collection[0].selection //2
```

Where are selectedIndex and index defined in your code? It looks like one of them is causing the problem. You may have to convert them to Int like `Int(selectedIndex)`.

Comment: Actually I call that in a method.Those two are parameters from the method. By the way the code is fine in playground, but not in my project.